# some users get "No item with the given ID could be found, or you do not have permission to access it" error

Tags: google-apps-script

i have an appscript running fine with most of the users. some users, however, get this error when trying to run the script: (they have the same permission as the other users that runs the script fine): "No item with the given ID could be found, or you do not have permission to access it"
any ideas?
thanks !

Comment: If you can, please add some code example and full error message

Comment: Please provide a code sample where the error is occurring and the error log too. Thanks

Comment: Hello, since this looks related to your account, I recommend you to head over G Suite Support [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

I have seen plenty of login/authentication problems with my app during past few days. For me, the error was `"Exception: You do not have permission to call Session.getActiveUser."`. The problem is random, occurs quite often (approx 25% of user logins), and my solution was to try again until successful. So, this might explain your problems as well.

Try to add for example:

```js
var email_act = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
```

to some place into your script and see if you get errors as well.

Comment: thanks!well, it's not random, there is a pattern. first 5 users run the script just fine (never had this error before), 3 new users i've added get this error.... i thought it was something with limited user number but i see no such limitation on thier account... (we use Gsuite)